# android developers - timer application

Tags: java, android

I wrote a timer code. the clear function doesn't clear the time value (when I press clear only the text changes, but the time value continues form stop point) here is the code, any suggestions to activate the clear button?:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button startButton;     
    private Button stopButton;  
    private Button clearButton;
    private TextView timeValue;     
    private long timeStart = 0L;
    private Handler timeHandler = new Handler();
    long timeInMilisec = 0L;
    long timeMemo = 0L;
    long timeUpdate = 0L;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        timeValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timeValue);        
        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);      
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

            public void onClick(View view) {

                timeStart = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();     
                timeHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0); 

            }

        });

        stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);        
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       

            public void onClick(View view) {        
                timeMemo += timeInMilisec;      
                timeHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread); 

            }

        });
     clearButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearButton);
     clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.clearButton:

                timeValue.setText("00:00:00");
                int secs = 0;       
                int mins = 0;       
                secs = 0;   
                int milliseconds = 0;
                timeInMilisec = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - timeStart;     
                timeUpdate = timeMemo + timeInMilisec;      
                timeValue.setText("" + mins + ":"       
                        + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"     
                        + String.format("%03d", milliseconds)); 

                timeHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(updateTimerThread);
                timeValue.setText("00:00:00");

                break;                  
            }                   
        }
    });

    }

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {       

        public void run() {

            timeInMilisec = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - timeStart;     
            timeUpdate = timeMemo + timeInMilisec;      
            int secs = (int) (timeUpdate / 1000);       
            int mins = secs / 60;       
            secs = secs % 60;       
            int milliseconds = (int) (timeUpdate % 1000);       
            timeValue.setText("" + mins + ":"       
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"     
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));     
            timeHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);

        }

    };      


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the ClearButton onClick you are not reseting the value of the "timerstart" and "timeMemo" variables. That is why only the text is being updated but the timer is not being reset.

Answer (score 0):

You should reset the **timeMemo** variable.

```
clearButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.clearButton:

            // Clear the timestart and timeMemo
            timeMemo = 0L;

            timeValue.setText("00:00:00");
            int secs = 0;       
            int mins = 0;       
            secs = 0;   
            int milliseconds = 0;
            timeInMilisec = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - timeStart;     
            timeUpdate = timeMemo + timeInMilisec;      
            timeValue.setText("" + mins + ":"       
                    + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"     
                    + String.format("%03d", milliseconds)); 

            timeHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(updateTimerThread);
            timeValue.setText("00:00:00");
            timeHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerThread);

            break;         
        }                   
    }
});
```

Comment: You are welcome :) BTW you should mark the answer as correct.